# Migrated to dedicated MariaDB makes app slower

Tags: performance, mariadb

I'm new to dba stackexchange, hope you can help me :-)

I do have a Hetzner root server (EX52-NVMe  Intel Core i7-8700 Hexa Core    64 GB DDR4  2× 1024 GB NVMe SSD) and Docker on it. At first, it was enough to start playing, but since ~2 years, I started tow public Friendica (https://friendi.ca/) instances, which are REALLY DB intensive. I used the "Docker best practices" and started a MariaDB Instance for each app.

I noticed that the overall performance dropped and added the following config to each of the two big MariaDB instances to increase it:

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema = ON

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 52G
innodb_log_file_size = 13G
innodb_read_io_threads = 6
innodb_write_io_threads = 6

innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_default_row_format = dynamic

max_connections = 150
wait_timeout = 900
interactive_timeout = 4000

table_open_cache = 4200
table_definition_cache = 2500

join_buffer_size = 11M
table_definition_cache = 2097152

optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
optimizer_switch = 'rowid_filter=off'

open_files_limit = 102400

log_bin
log_basename = opensocial
```

It helped a little - but the I/O is still high and the overall performance isn't satisfied.

So - I ordered a new Root Server with another 128GB RAM and Core i7 and dedicated this server to a MariaDB standalone-server.

I start it with the following settings:

```
[mysqld]

pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
tmpdir                  = /tmp

skip-name-resolve
bind-address            = 10.0.3.3

performance_schema

sql_mode = NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

wait_timeout        = 900
interactive_timeout = 4000

optimizer_use_condition_selectivity = 1
optimizer_switch = 'rowid_filter=off'

character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 80G
innodb_file_per_table           = ON
innodb_default_row_format       = dynamic
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 64M
innodb_log_file_size            = 20G
innodb_ft_cache_size            = 20000000

innodb_read_io_threads  = 12
innodb_write_io_threads = 12

# mysqltuner improvements
join_buffer_size       = 64M
table_definition_cache = 2097152
tmp_table_size         = 32M
max_heap_table_size    = 32M
key_buffer_size        = 32M
table_open_cache       = 4200
```

But the overall performance is now much more worse than before and I'm struggling, because the I/O , RAM , CPU is OK:
[image: I/O Dashboard]
[image: CPU/RAM/Filesystem]

It takes around ~4-5 seconds for the database queries to load the default network page of https://friendica.me and about ~7-8 seconds for the database queries to load a community page.

The other instance https://opensocial.at is still running on the "old" Docker environment and much faster (but it's ~30% bigger than friendica.me)

So can you help me to find the bottleneck at my dedicated mariadb root-server?

Many thanks! :)

Comment: Enable [slow query log](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/slow-query-log-overview/) for the server, set a long query time to ~1 second or less, and see what queries come out as being slow. Using [ANALYzE FORMAT=JSON](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/analyze-format-json/) see what the query execution is like. Which MariaDB version?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple Dockers, each configured as if it has all 64GB available?

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 52G   -- and other settings
```

Each instance of MariaDB needs to have only a share of the total RAM allocation.  (This addresses bnth I/O and RAM issues.  CPU is rarely an issue with MariaDB.)

> started a MariaDB Instance for each app.

That may or may not be beneficial.  MariaDB can handle lots of connections quite efficiently.  Please describe the various apps so we can discuss whether on instance or many would be best.